# Digits that are insignificant by virtue of representing extremely small quantities within a much larger quantity: what are they called?

Tags: terminology, approximation

In computer science, sometimes we can measure run-times with high accuracy.  As a hypothetical scenario, suppose a computation takes a week to run and we can measure the run-time accurate to the nearest minute.

We might write this run-time as 7.1234 days, where all of these digits are [significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures).

However, from a human point of view, there's no meaningful distinction between 7.1234 days and 7.12 days.  The omitted 0.0034 days is a drop in the ocean compared to the total run time; the digits 3 and 4 represent such a small proportion of the total quantity that they're irrelevant (despite being measured correctly).

*Question*: Is there a name for digits that are insignificant simply by virtue of representing extremely small quantities within a much larger quantity?

Comment: Not specifically statistics terms but I'm put in mind of [*unnecessary precision*](http://staringatemptypages.blogspot.com/2009/12/unnecessary-precision.html) and [*ludicrous precision*](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LudicrousPrecision).

Comment: In CS, you can talk about the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_significant_bit in a binary representation of numbers.

Comment: Just because a human can have no appreciation for precision does not make it unnecessary or not useful. Some problems are so unstable that precision is needed to solve them, whether or not the numbers "seem" to be used usefully. For example, the typical regression problem will output only half the number of significant digits as are allowed for in the input. In general, error propagation for more complicated problems eats up precision something fierce. One can eat up an initial 50 place precision number to have 4 significant digits to finish, and problems can be quite inhuman.